# Simulating Length function to get a list's length

Tags: list, function, wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to simulate the Length function in Mathematica v.8 to get the length of a list. Given this facts:

- Empty list is represented as {}
- l = Rest[l] assigns to l (which is a list) the list l without the first element
- a While loop

It's my first year using mathematica and I'm not too good at this so there's probably something (or everything) wrong with what I'm doing:

```
Ej1[l_List] := Module[{i, v},
v = {{}};
i = 1;
While[l != v, l = Rest[l]; i++]
Return[i]
]
```

l={a,b,c,d,e};

When I try to run it the loop never ends and it gives me this warnings:

```
Set::shape: Lists {a,b,c,d,e} and {b,c,d,e} are not the same shape. >>

Set::shape: Lists {a,b,c,d,e} and {b,c,d,e} are not the same shape. >>

Set::shape: Lists {a,b,c,d,e} and {b,c,d,e} are not the same shape. >>

General::stop: Further output of Set::shape will be suppressed during this calculation. >>
```

Answer (score 9):

The main problems were that you were trying to modify the input variable, `l`, which is not possible, and you had a missing semi-colon.

```
Ej1[l_List] := Module[{i = 0, v = {}, thisl},
  thisl = l;
  While[thisl != v, thisl = Rest[thisl]; i++];
  i]
```

Answer (score 6):

You can also use `NestWhile`:

```
Clear[f];
f[l_List] := NestWhile[{Rest[#[[1]]], (#[[2]]) + 1} &, {l, 0}, 
   (#[[1]] != {}) &][[2]]
```

This code isn't bounded by `$RecursionLimit` or `$IterationLimit` so it also works for very large lists. The downside is that it isn't very efficient since in every iteration step a copy is made of the remaining list. A faster way of counting elements in a list is to do something like

```
f2[l_List] := Fold[(# + 1) &, 0, l]
```

As a comparison:

```
list=RandomReal[1,10000];
Timing[f[list]]
(* ==> {3.35747, 10000} *)

Timing[f2[list]]
(* ==> {0.000658, 10000} *)
```

Comment: +1. The speedup is so dramatic because `Fold` is able to auto-compile the folded function.

Answer (score 4):

```
length[myList_List] := Module[{x = 0}, Scan[x++ &, myList]; x]

length[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g}]

==> 7
```

Answer (score 3):

Recursively, using `If[]`:

```
ClearAll[f];

f[l_List, i_: 0] := If[l != {}, f[Rest[l], i + 1], i];

f[{1,2}]
(*
-> 2
*)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is yet another recursive solution, in what I would argue is fairly idiomatic functional programming:

```
myLength[{}] := 0
myLength[lis_List] := 1 + myLength[Rest[lis]]

In[47]:= myLength[{}]
Out[47]= 0

In[48]:= myLength[{1}]
Out[48]= 1

In[49]:= myLength[{1,2,3,4,5}]
Out[49]= 5
```

Comment: Hah, thanks! I'm still very busy, and honestly it's hard to find an unanswered question nowadays, but that's a good thing!

Comment: +1 -- I still think Sjoerd's code is easier from most backgrounds, but this is great.

Answer (score 1):

Same as belisarius but without explicitly writing `If`:

```
ClearAll[ej2];
ej2[lst_ /; (lst == {}), i_: 0] := i
ej2[lst_, i_: 0] := ej2[Rest[lst], i + 1]

ej2[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]
(*
5
*)
```

Comment: I just noticed you posted the same answer 3 minutes before.  If you correct yours so that  it works with {} as well, I'll delete mine

Comment: @Szabolcs good point, I had removed the `:0` to debug something else and forgot to put it back... No need to remove yours though